# React class components redirect under conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get React to navigate to the main page when certain conditions are met using the following code.

```js
import './App.scss';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import World from './components/World';
import Shop from './components/Shop';
import About from './components/About';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            query: ''
        };
    }
    render() {
        <BrowserRouter>
           { (window.location.pathname !== '/' ? <Navigate to="/" /> : '') }
           ...
        </BrowserRouter>
    }
}
```

This works, it does only navigate to '/' when the current location isn't '/', when it gets there it throws the following error which suggests an ifinite loop, the code works fine though (as far as I can tell).

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly use that function in other funcs than render() function?

Comment: You should write redirection code in `componentDidMount` and then use `props.history.push` to navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using react-router v6 you can do something like this

```
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate  to={"/"}/>} />
```

Comment: Thanks, this puts me on the right path